# How do I get some data from a website which requires authentication with Ansbile?

Tags: ansible, python-module

I have been trying to login a web page and get/download some specific data from there, but couldn't make it. Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of authentication do the websites use? Ansible does support a few different auth methods including basic auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to download a specific file, and you can get it via http://username:password@example.com/path/file.conf then you can use the get_url module:

```
- name: < Fetch file that requires authentication.
  get_url:
    url: http://example.com/path/file.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
    url_username: bar
    url_password: '{{ mysecret }}'
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need arbitrary auth, why not just write it in normal python/bash and trigger the script with Ansible so that you aren't constrained by Ansible's auth support?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html